# How to keep rows with data always at the top of the spreadsheet without filtering

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I'm working on a project and am in need of some help. I am wondering if there is a way that I can have A3 move to A2 automatically after data in A2 is deleted? For example, if there is data in A3,A5, and A6, but A1 and A4 are empty the information in A3,A5, and A6 moves up. Another question I have is could I get that data to be sorted based on the timestamp so the oldest data is first? I essentially always want data in the top 10 columns so it's less scrolling. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can do this with script

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm very knew to google sheets and have been searching and searching for help but cannot find any examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script will solve both your questions:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");           // SHEET NAME
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:I");                // RANGE TO BE SORTED

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 8, ascending: false}]);     // 8th COLUMN = H COLUMN
}
```

---

### update:

```
function onEdit(e){
 script1(e);
 script2(e);
 }

function script1(e){
 var row = e.range.getRow();
 var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 1 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Kanban"){
   e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).setValue(new Date());
   }
  }

function script2(e){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kanban");          
 var range = sheet.getRange("A2:I");
  range.sort([{column: 8, ascending: false}]);   
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does the range need to be the last row or can it just be I? Also, it still doesnt push A3 put to A2 so I'm still looking for information and tips on how to do that. Again, appreciate your time helping me

Comment: player0, the second image is what it looks like now after entering that code. It still doesnt sort column 8 timestamp. Do you think its because the timestamp is being generated in that came column with script? I dont know if we can overwrite that

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-Dp-wKRi1y7Dwr13iTdyHh-1L4F0OkjZXWgdn-sRhA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so how do I fix that?

Comment: Can I add the two together?

Comment: when i try and run the script it still saying 'range' of undefined. It does work though so thank you. so essentially this code is pushing data up once the data is cleared in that row am i correct?

Comment: @noahfish5 answer updated. here is a working sheet with a script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17jnUvZ_121crKFFGwK4_SZD7Ymj2Teubgt8V6fuGmdI/copy (script needs to be authorized ofc)

Comment: everthing works great!! Thanks man, I truly appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me!!

Comment: Why can I only edit the document? When another user tries to it doesn’t work for them

Comment: yes, that's because the other users did not install the script. that's the biggest drawback ("security measure") of scripts - every user needs to install them otherwise they won't fire for them

Comment: in your case the script is onEdit so perhaps you could just add =NOW() in some side cell and in spreadsheet settings set recalculation on every minute. if that won't work you can set up a time trigger so the script will fire in set intervals from your account so ppl will not need to install scripts but ofc the change won't be instant ofc.

Comment: Would it be because some of the columns have permissions?

Comment: I'm willing to do the timestamp whatever way possible as long as everyone can use the spreadsheet like I can. How it is right now is good, however its important that the spreadsheet sorts for everyone, not just myself so whatever way you think is best I would like to try

Comment: I get that I'm still confused on permissions and how to create a time trigger script. Sorry man very new to scripts and google sheets

Comment: this has nothing to do with column permissions. triggers for scripts can be managed at https://script.google.com/home/triggers and created in script editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGhl5.png

Comment: So is the trigger function to run: edit, script1, script2? The spreadsheet is working so well i just dont know how to fix it and i appreciate you taking time out of your day man Im just lost

Comment: open your spreadsheet. open your script editor. select alarm clock. do: https://i.imgur.com/FLIOw5p.png then do: https://i.imgur.com/JCBO8Xt.png done. trigger will run every minute and sort things up for everyone who did not install the script

Comment: I tried that and it still only moves up for me. I went on a seconardy account that isnt the owner and when i delete data in row 2, data in row 3 still doesnt move up to row 2. copy of the spreadsheet. compensation for your time will be made. I did what you said which is shown in the script.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zBkFwf8GN-xrYV6z15wcxKaon8untW2uk942pEIUKcg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: for your 2nd accout it will never sort out right after you delete row because your 2nd accoun did not installed script. after you delete row via your 2nd account you need to wait 1-2 minutes so that trigger would catch up and sort those rows. in theory this should work. I have almost 0 script knowledge so I apologize for that. perhaps your script needs to be renamed to onChange script or if onEdit cant be triggered by trigger then you need to add sorting script separately and call it from trigger as XYZ function.

Comment: Is authorizing after running a script different from installing script? I got an email saying it failed so I’m guessing it’s not working overall. This is far over my head why is why I was looking for help

Comment: authorizing script = installing script

Comment: So multiple people can authorize the script